# Transferring range of rows to another tab, then clearing tab without removing formulas

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, range, transfer

In Google Sheets, I'm trying to transfer range A3:G13(if there is text; sometimes the entire range will not be used) from the Packing List tab to the Completed Transactions tab when G16 is set to "Complete" and then clear A3:G13 without removing the formulas.  I have seen many scripts that transfer rows individually but I need them all to transfer onEdit of G15.

Thanks for your help!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1raVbOHsjwK1EHDnIO7jKo1oH4GQXsbfjBD2ormcO87I/edit?ts=5fd250e3#gid=0

#### Code:

```
function onEdit(event) { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet(); 
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange(); 
  if(s.getName() == "Packing List" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "Complete") { 
    var range = r.getRange(A3:G13); 
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn(); 
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completed Transactions"); 
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1); 
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target); 
    s.deleteRow(row);
```

Comment: The spreadsheet you shared is not public, can you make it public? Also, can you show what you tried till now? Do you have a code you're working? Which specific issue are you facing?

Comment: Sorry, the updated link is now public.

Comment: Do you have any code you're working on? Do you want to keep the range formatting and formulas, when copied to the target sheet?

Comment: I tried piecing together parts of the code, but nothing worked so I deleted it all.  I'm not very adept at using Scripts so was trying to  start with this sample code that individually takes rows to another sheet, but I need it to be grouped together and only when G16 is set to Complete.  I do not need the formulas to be copied to the target sheet, just the values.

Comment: function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Packing List" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "Complete") {
    var range = r.getRange(A3:G13);
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completed Transactions");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

- Retrieve the values from the source range with [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues), filter out the rows where column A is empty with [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), and set the filtered values with [setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues).
- Retrieve the formulas of the source range using [getFormulas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformulas), and set them again with [setFormulas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulasformulas) after the content has been cleared.
- Clear the content of the source range with [clearContent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent).

#### Code snippet:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const rangeNotation = e.range.getA1Notation();
  const editedSheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (editedSheet.getName() === "Packing List" && rangeNotation === "G15" && e.value === "Complete") {
    const sourceRange = editedSheet.getRange("A3:G13");
    const sourceFormulas = sourceRange.getFormulas();
    const sourceData = sourceRange.getValues().filter(row => row[0] != "");
    const targetSheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Completed Transactions");
    const targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, sourceData.length, sourceData[0].length);
    targetRange.setValues(sourceData);
    sourceRange.clearContent();
    sourceRange.setFormulas(sourceFormulas);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked Great! Really appreciate your help